# mdadm array doesn't assemble on boot

Tags: server, mdadm

Following this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-18-04 on creating a Raid5 array on Ubuntu server 18.04.

The array creates fine with 6 devices.

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
```

I run mount the array and confirm it is active and working.

I save the array config with

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Add the file system mount options for automatic mounting at boot

```
echo '/dev/md0 /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Reboot, and the array is in active, only has 3 devices and is labeled as a raid 0 array.

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 3

              Name : server:0  (local to host server)
              UUID : d18084d0:9af59a76:89452b88:fa403326
            Events : 3700

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       64        -        /dev/sde
       -       8       80        -        /dev/sdf
       -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
```

I have been through these steps twice now with exactly the same result and when the array takes upwards of 6 hours to fully create this is a painfully slow process.

Note: this is a new array and no worry for data loss.

Edit: Added Answer

Turns out that I needed to create the partitions on each disk first, then when creating the array point to the partition instead pf the raw disk.

so

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose --assume-clean  /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
```

instead of

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose --assume-clean  /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
```

After this the array would assemble and then mount on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to create the partitions on each disk first, then when creating the array point to the partition instead pf the raw disk.

so

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose --assume-clean  /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
```

instead of

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose --assume-clean  /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
```

After this the array would assemble and then mount on boot.